# SQL Sum by Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a invoices table like this:

| Group | Client | Invoice Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | John | 250 |
| Group 1 | John | 250 |
| Group 2 | Debra | 250 |

I would like to display the report as:

| Group | Client | Invoice Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | John | 500 |
| Group 2 | Debra | 250 |

Essentially I'd like to sum by group.

To achieve this, the code that I've tried is:

```sql
select dbo.Clients.Groups,
       dbo.ClientInvoices.Amount
from   dbo.Clients
       INNER JOIN dbo.ClientInvoices ON dbo.Clients.Groups = dbo.Clients.Groups
```

Is anyone able to advise how to achieve this?

Comment: The join condition does not looks correct `dbo.Clients.Groups = dbo.Clients.Groups`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Here's an example (you might need to change the column names for your exact use case)

```sql
SELECT Clients.Group,
       Clients.Client,
       SUM(ClientInvoices.Amount) AS Amount
FROM   Clients
       LEFT JOIN ClientInvoices ON Clients.Group = ClientInvoices.Group
GROUP BY Clients.Group, Clients.Client
```

Comment: Your code worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a  group by   or  Window function for solve your problem

```
select 
          a.[Group]
         ,a.Client
         ,a.Amount as [Invoice Amount]
from (
            SELECT c.[Group],
                   c.Client,
                   sum(ci.Amount) over(
                                         partition by 
                                                        c.[Group]
                                                      , c.Client
                                       ) as Amount,
                   row_number() over(  partition by c.[Group], c.Client order by c.[Group], c.Client) as rw

            FROM   Clients c
                   LEFT JOIN ClientInvoices ci ON c.[Group] = ci.[Group]
       )a
       where a.rw=1
```

You can to insert the basic data with the following codes

```
drop table if exists Clients
drop table if exists ClientInvoices
create table  Clients([Group] varchar(100),Client varchar(100))
create table  ClientInvoices([Group] varchar(100),Amount int)

insert into Clients([Group],Client)
          select 'Group 1','John' 
union all select 'Group 1','John' 
union all select 'Group 2','Debra'

insert into ClientInvoices([Group],Amount)
          select 'Group 1',250 
union all select 'Group 2', 250
```